# Command to build/run typescript project with NX

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo

I am trying to run typescript file (within an app) that depends on a couple libraries with NX but I can not figure out how to do it. I've tried numerous methods, here are a couple ways I tried:

**First Try**

```
  "cron": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
            "command": "ts-node apps/src/cron.ts"
      }
    },
```

I get the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './cron.ts'
Require stack: ...
```

**Second Try**

I've also tried the following:

```
"build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/js:tsc",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "platform": "node",
        "target": "node14",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/cron",
        "tsConfig": "apps/cron/tsconfig.app.json",
        "main": "apps/crons/src/cmd/run-token-trade-counts-cron.ts"
      }
    },
```

This time it manages to compile correctly, but i get the following error when I run the executable:

```
nx run cron:cron

Error: Cannot find module '@company/logger'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm facing a very similar issue, did you end up finding a solution ?